# Error while upgrading from 1.4.4.2 to 1.4.4.3 or higher

Tags: meteor

I faced below error when I ran below commands;

1. `meteor update --patch`
2. ran command `meteor`

**ERROR**

```
D:\test>meteor update --patch

Changes to your project's package version selections from updating the
release:

accounts-base              upgraded from 1.2.17 to 1.3.0
babel-compiler             upgraded from 6.18.2 to 6.19.1
boilerplate-generator      upgraded from 1.0.11 to 1.1.0
dynamic-import             added, version 0.1.0
ecmascript                 upgraded from 0.7.3 to 0.8.0
ecmascript-runtime         upgraded from 0.3.15 to 0.4.1
ecmascript-runtime-client  added, version 0.4.1
ecmascript-runtime-server  added, version 0.4.1
localstorage               upgraded from 1.0.12 to 1.1.0
meteor-base                upgraded from 1.0.4 to 1.1.0
minifier-js                upgraded from 2.0.0 to 2.1.0
minimongo                  upgraded from 1.0.23 to 1.2.0
modules                    upgraded from 0.8.2 to 0.9.0
modules-runtime            upgraded from 0.7.10 to 0.8.0
mongo                      upgraded from 1.1.17 to 1.1.18
promise                    upgraded from 0.8.8 to 0.8.9
reactive-dict              upgraded from 1.1.8 to 1.1.9
standard-minifier-js       upgraded from 2.0.0 to 2.1.0
webapp                     upgraded from 1.3.15 to 1.3.16

test: updated to Meteor 1.4.4.3.

D:\test>meteor
[[[[[ ~\D\test ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Meteor 1.5 is available. Update this project with 'meteor update'.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While selecting package versions:
   error: Potentially incompatible change required to top-level
   dependency: meteor-base 1.0.4, was 1.1.0.
   Constraints on package "meteor-base":
   * meteor-base@1.0.4 <- top level
   * meteor-base@1.0.4 <- top level

   Potentially incompatible change required to top-level dependency:
   dynamic-import 0.1.0-beta.20, was 0.1.0.
   Constraints on package "dynamic-import":

   To allow potentially incompatible changes to top-level dependencies,
   you must pass --allow-incompatible-update on the command line.

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: ```.meteor/pacakges``` ==> what versions are specified here?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue.

Comment: @Juliomac: Well Friend! what I did is, I uninstalled entire `meteor` from machine, reinstalled it again, transferred my code to new folder(created using `meteor create --full project`). Now! it works fine. I did'nt have much time to find the exact cause or solution :(. The one I did is easy and takes couple of minutes.

Comment: Thanks @AnkurSoni, but then I would loose all my git history and branches. Does not seem to be a solution for me...

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your git management. You must save only your developed code on git. Doing this will not affect anything sensitive. I just reinstalled my meteor with latest version, that is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that the update included package `"dynamic-import"`.

Just taking it out solved the issue. Then run with:

`meteor --allow-incompatible-update`

Maybe it is just a coincidence I have made this patch just a bit after the new Meteor 1.5 is launched. I wonder if this package should not be in this release.

Answer (score 2):

if you update to meteor 1.5 with `meteor update` Everything will work as expected with 0 conflict.
Dont touch any files!
Worked for me, first update that actually does not break anything.